# Cordova ionic - google analytics integration. AdvertisingIdClient$Info exception

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, ionic-framework

I have a ionic project, I want to add google analytics and I use `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics` command to add it.

It wokrs fine with ios, but when I build it for android, it throws the exception below.

My cordova version is `5.4.1` . And other plugins list is below:

```
"cordova-plugin-contacts",
"cordova-plugin-camera",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-transport-security",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
"com.ionic.keyboard",
"com.google.playservices"
```

Error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexArmv7Debug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        /Users/fatih/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /development/workspace/mobile/app-mobile/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/armv7/debug --input-list=/development/workspace/mobile/app-mobile/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/armv7/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
        2
  Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: Hello. Have you found solutions for this problem?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: No, I tried so many things, but couldn't success

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Managed to resolve it by manually removing `google-play-services.jar` from the built platform (that is, after I ran `cordova platform add android`).

The JAR is located in `platforms/android/libs`.

Hope this will help!